# Why is it that every time I check out a branch on git I have to re-run pod update pod install?

Tags: git, cocoapods

Why is it that every time I check out a branch on git I have to re-run pod update / pod install?

error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

Comment: You should only do this if you have different Podfiles on each branch. For example you added a pod on a new branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other people in the group had different library versions on their branch.

Therefore I have to install the same library versions they are using when I switch to those branches.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you **podfile.lock** is out of sync with the **manifest.lock** file. Those 2 files work together to keep track of the last install. So, someone previously did a pod install and CP is telling you that you also should do a install for your current version.